# Getting wrong viewport dimentions on Firefox Mobile browser only

Tags: javascript

I was testing a script which works fine on almost all desktop browsers and Android's chrome browser but when I tested it on Android version of Firefox Mobile browser I'm got wrong viewport dimensions.

So I decided to put together a small script to log the viewport dimensions at three stages [init (before load), after load and after a 1 second timeout]

http://kraftpixel.in/test/viewport.html

This is what I receive on my Moto-E android phone.
Also I noticed 'Dimensions after load' are random, On one occasion I noticed w=980 h=480 after load but presently I get the following result.

```
Initial dimensions : w=980 h=480
Dimensions after load : w=360 h=519
1 Sec after load via setTimeout() : w=360 h=519
```

Can someone please test this behavior on their android phone using the Firefox Mobile browser?

Suggestions are welcome but I need to execute the script before onLoad.
Its a script similar to those '(Pre)loading screens' on some websites.

Comment: Did you figure reason for such behavior of Firefox mobile? I do have similar situation http://stackoverflow.com/q/27804574/1673000

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that you and after some research I found that to have those properties correctly initialized you should wait until [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) is fired.

Try to modify your script using that event instead of onload and you will have the same result that when you fire the log function one second after load.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded