# Unexpected viewport size for mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, html

I was testing different viewport sizes for various mobile browsers using the code below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Browser details</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        window.onload = function (e) {
            var width = document.getElementById("width");
            var height = document.getElementById("height");

            var w = window.innerWidth;
            var h = window.innerHeight;

            width.innerHTML = w;
            height.innerHTML = h;

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="">Viewport Width x Height : <span id="width"></span> x <span id="height"></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested my code on **Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9500**. The output for different Android browsers is :

Google Chrome   : 360 x 559

Mozilla Firefox : 980 x 480

Default Browser : 360 x 592

Why so much difference for mozilla firefox? I expect the output should be around **360 X 5--** (five hundred ..something)

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery instead;

```
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();
```

Comment: It's same thing, only difference is I am trying to use JavaScript instead of jQuery; and even if I use jQuery the result is same.

Comment: Try to use the same script but without ` window.onload = function (e) {` because maybe firefox execute  your code before executing the meta code